# How to make an extension app which provide resource for a main app

Tags: android, android-resources

I have an app which need some built-in resources and let users to search on those resource. Those resources are not static, I will update it sometimes, and because Google Play required APK file be no more than 50MB (it's documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html)), so I want to divided my app into 2 or more apps with a main app and others provide resources for the main app.

Like this one:

- Aviary - Main App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aviary.android.feather&feature=search_result
- Aviary - I call this "resource app": https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aviary.android.feather.plugins.stickers.free_stickers&feature=search_result

Explain about Aviary: in the main app of Aviary, there's a function which required the resource app in order to run. The resource app doesn't have any activities, and whenever the resource app is installed, the function will be available.

So my question is: how to make a resource app like that? Moreover, I also want the resource app to be able to provide some database for the main app for searching purpose once it's installed.

I thought about ContentProvider, but it seems only can provide database, I don't know what to do with real resource like images or media files.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at the play store expansion files - http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: @jcw I did, but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for, I want to make a separated APK file which can provide both database and resource, not just free hosting.